# How can I know from where are the current threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a server in C# that uses sockets to communicate with its clients. The problem comes when on certain occasions the number of threads used by the server suddenly increases.

Use the following function to get the number of Themes:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count
```

I want to know if there is any way to know where they come from in order to fix the code. I have tried with the thread window in Debug mode in Visual Studio, but it does not give me any information about those threads, they have no name and no information.

Comment: Step through the code and determine what is spawning threads

Comment: They are either Framework threads, for things like garbage collection, ThreadPool threads, or explicitly created threads.  Framework threads are nothing to worry about, and the ThreadPool is fairly safe.  Any other threads must have been explicitly created with `new Thread()`, which should be easily searchable.

Comment: Yes, they are either Framework threads but it make my server work slow, and I do not know why it was created.

Comment: I think I have a deadlock, but I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: @Robercid Why would you think that?

Comment: Maybe I have got a problem in a lock.

Comment: Are you creating any threads in your code? If so, are you using `new Thread()` or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to do so? As has been mentioned, you need not worry about the Framework threads. And please quantify the thread count after the sudden increase.

Answer (score 0):

You can name threads like this so you know where they came from:

```
Thread th = Thread.CurrentThread;
th.Name = "MainThread";
Console.WriteLine("This is {0}", th.Name);
```

Make sure you have "using System.Threading;" in your program.

Example pulled from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm